# Problems with using CAPTCHA test keys in automation

Tags: automated-testing

I've seen this [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12416/19318) regarding the Google CAPTCHA test site key and secret key.

How would that be of use while automating through HP UFT?

Reference:
[Automation and bypassing Google No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12416/19318)

Comment: Do you mean to refer to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-automation?

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12416/19318

Comment: Whose post have you seen?

Answer (score 0):

The solution using test keys is separate from test automation entirely.

Key use is embedded in the application. I recommend you approach development to implement a test mode in the application that applies the test keys, allowing CAPTCHA to pass automatically when running your test automation from the controlled test environment.

This behaviour is what you build your test automation on.

Comment: I was able to bypass the image validation by editing the site key with test key given by google at test run time. Fetched the iframe that has the site key, replaced and fired it again with java script . The problem thet i have now is to fetch the response  code and and send the secret key with it for server side validation. I am not able to figure out where to fetch this response  code from.